# AWS Cognito returns "NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password" when I run it from Jest

Tags: jestjs, amazon-cognito, ts-jest

I have this block of code:

```js
const aws = require("@aws-amplify/auth")

const config = {
  region: "...",
  userPoolId: "...",
  userPoolWebClientId: "...",
}

aws.Auth.configure(config)

const email = "me@example.com"
const password = "pass"

async function test() {
  const result = await aws.Auth.signIn(email, password)
  console.log(result)
}

test()
```

It works as expected and AWS Cognito authenticates the user successfully. However, when I run it with jest:

```js
describe("authenticateUser", () => {
  it("why is this failing?", async () => {
    const aws = require("@aws-amplify/auth")

    const config = {
      region: "...",
      userPoolId: "...",
      userPoolWebClientId: "...",
    }

    aws.Auth.configure(config)

    const email = "me@example.com"
    const password = "pass"

    const result = await aws.Auth.signIn(email, password)
    console.log(result)
  })
})
```

Then I get "NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password." from AWS Cognito.

Can somebody tell me why this test acts like this??

Thank you!

Comment: You don’t have mock AWS Cognito authenticates, which will cause the real service to be called. If this is what you want, please check if your username and password are correct

Comment: Yes, I want to call the real service. If email/password were incorrect, then the first block of code would fail, too. But it does not fail and I know the credentials are valid.

Comment: When you say the top snippet works, you mean in the browser?

Comment: No. I just run "node test.js" and it works. However, when running with jest it fails.

Comment: Same result here

Comment: @mspoulsen [known issue with a fix here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/6552#issuecomment-801414073)